# How do I force an object to run as a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, object

I’ve been using node.js for some time now and I realized that `require` is a function, and an object, or so it seems. You can do the following:

```js
require('someModule')
let a = require.cache //not undefined
```

I’ve been trying to do this myself but I can’t figure out how. These are the things I tried:

```js
function a() {
console.log('a')
}
let a = {test: 1}
//throws cannot declare variable twice
```

And reversed it

```js
let a = {test:1}
function a() {
console.log('a')
}
//still throws
```

I even tried adding a `toFunction` method to a class, making an instance of it, and trying to call on the instance, which I hoped would work like `toString()`, but it still said `a is not a function`.

How can I do this myself? It’s probably super simple but I couldn’t find it anywhere when researching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the function first. Functions are objects, so you can then assign to a property of it.

```js
function a() {
  console.log('a')
}
a.test = 1;

a();
console.log(a.test);
```

If you want to use object literal syntax instead of assigning to properties individually, you can use `Object.assign`.

```js
function a() {
  console.log('a')
}
Object.assign(
  a,
  {
    test: 1,
    // other properties
  }
);

a();
console.log(a.test);
```